# I can't find the name of this anime with a witch whose only weakness was bleeding

Tags: deltora-quest

I watched it around 2009 but I can still remember lots of details.

- It involved a young boy, an older guy (a knight I think) and a girl going on a quest to find these stones/gems/whatever.
- The girl had a small pet... puffball thing, and a raven.
- There was a witch, sorceress something-or-other, and at one point the raven pecked her. Making her bleed was her only weakness, and so she died from that.
- There was an episode where they met a giant guarding a bridge, and he told them a riddle: "Tell me the truth, and I will kill you with my sword, tell me a lie and I will kill you with my bare hands". The boy said "you will kill me with your hands", which caused a paradox thing (If that was true, he would kill him with his sword, but then it would be a lie, so he would... yeah, you get the idea.)

That's all I can remember.

Answer (score 5):

It could be [**Deltora quest**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deltora_Quest_(anime)):

> The Shadow Lord, an evil sorcerer and The Lord of Shadows which comes from The Shadowlands, has taken over Deltora by destroying a magical object known as The Belt of Deltora, which is Deltora's only protection against him. Throughout the course of the anime, Lief, Barda and Jasmine travel around the land of Deltora to return the seven gem of the initials of which combine to form DELTORA, hence the name Deltora Quest, to the belt and save the land. Their first destination is the Forests of Silence.

[image: pic]

The three characters are:

> - **Lief:** At the start of the series, Lief is the son of a blacksmith who lives in the run down city of Del. He is (as Barda describes him) 'A young hot-head' and spends his time roaming the streets and both tempting and dodging trouble. On his 16th birthday he leaves Del on his father's quest to find the magical gems missing from the belt of Deltora and the heir destined to wear it. [...]
> - **Barda:** At the start of the series Barda appears to be a poor beggar living on the streets of Del. He is revealed to be an ex-palace guard who assumes the role of protector to Lief, much to both his and Lief's dismay. He is a skilled swordsman and frequently makes jokes about being stuck with two young hot-heads- Lief and Jasmine. [...]
> - **Jasmine:** At the start of the series Jasmine is a wild orphan girl who lives a solitary life in the dangerous Forests of Silence. She has messy coal black hair which frames her elfin like face and emerald green eyes. She is often described as impatient and lonely but with a good heart. Her only friends in the Forests are the raven named Kree and a small furry animal called Filli. Jasmine understands the language of trees and many other animals. [...]

They met the giant guarding a bridge (see picture below)  in [Episode 4](https://youtu.be/bpd02P998t4?t=6m). The guard asked each person a riddle, and allowed only the ones who solved their riddles to cross the bridge. [The paradoxical riddle](https://youtu.be/bpd02P998t4?t=14m32s) was given to Lief after he failed to answer the riddle given to him.

[image]

The scene with the raven pecking the sorceress (see picture below) happens in [Episode 7](https://youtu.be/zHqcK1tx8AM?t=15m56s).

[image]

Comment: Oh my... I read the books back when I was a kid... If only I'd known there was an anime =)